# Having Error while Loading Tensorflow 1.x Model in Tensorflow 2.x

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-science, tensorflow2.0

I am Loading my saving model of Tensorflow 1.x in Tensorflow 2.x and i am having issue

I am using this code

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense,Flatten
from tensorflow.python.keras import Sequential
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
model_file_name = os.path.join("my_drive/AI_values/model", 'model.ckpt')# CHANGE MODEL NAME
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_file_name)
```

I am having error

```
OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'my_drive/AI_values/model/model.ckpt', 
errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

It's showing os error which is permission and also showing unable to open file but i try both .ckpt and .h5 formatt but not working.

Pls help me out i am sharing my model google drive link

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tPoUDM5Re3ZKXwK2f7kbzwK8Lad6vtCX

Also google colab link

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hf7AwEMJHf4zLZOBSzxejA2ISuTQ3N9K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you replace `my_drive` with `My Drive` (including the space) in

`model_file_name = os.path.join("my_drive/AI_values/model", 'model.ckpt')`

and try?

Comment: I also can not load your saved model files, but I can load my own files easily. I think the problem is in the way you are saving them. How are you saving your model h5 file/checkpoint?

Comment: This is Tensorflow v1 file where model is successfully implement and loaded

https://drive.google.com/file/d/11zRTzwYt9Dv7oq3g0z2PElkoU7dXw8yC/view?usp=sharing

problem is not loaded in version 2

Comment: Dataset link

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iAZUqDdx2EHG7iClutjfcKxfFJES5RK3